# Customization data prototype wysiwyg

Tags: forms, symfony, collections

I have a problem of personalization of a data prototype. I do not understand why my textarea does not take TinyMCE while the textarea at the top takes it ...

Here my code and a picture of my problem.

```
                            {% import _self as formMacroSections %}

                        {% macro printMacroSections(section) %}
                            <div class="row js-section-item">
                                <div class="input-container">
                                    <label for="title" class="rl-label required">Titre de la partie</label>
                                    {{ form_widget(section.title) }}
                                </div>
                                <div class="input-container">
                                    <label for="content" class="rl-label required">Contenu</label>
                                    {{ form_widget(section.content, {'attr' : {'class' : 'form-control tinymce' }}) }}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        {% endmacro %}

                        <div class="wrapper js-section-wrapper"
                             data-prototype="{{ formMacroSections.printMacroSections(form.sections.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}"
                             data-index="{{ form.sections|length }}"
                        >
                            {% for section in form.sections %}
                                {{ formMacroSections.printMacroSections(section) }}
                            {% endfor %}
                            <a href="#" class="js-section-add">
                                <span id="add_section" class="buttonblue">Ajouter une partie <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
```

My form type :

```
            ->add('content', TextareaType::class, [
            'label' => false,
            'required' => true,
            'attr' => [
                'class' => '.tinymce',
                'theme' => 'modern',
                'data-theme' => 'section_tutorial',
            ],
        ]);
```

And the picture :
[image]

As you can see, the textarea on the top take TinyMCE, but on the bottom of the picture, it doesn't :(

Somebody could explain my mistake ?
Regards,
Christophe

Comment: how the tinymce.init is called?
You should have a look at : https://www.tinymce.com/docs/get-started/multiple-editors/

Comment: TinyMCE is called at the bottom of the page with " {{ tinymce_init() }}" and as you can notice it work for one textarea upon the second one :(

Comment: Have you tried the link?

Comment: Sorry for the answer delay, and oh ok, we had to init multiple instance of tinymce, i think it will solve my problems, thanks :)